# Index over multiple fields

Tags: mysql, index, index-tuning

I have a table with ~40 million entries and I have an index for most of my fields. All my queries are optimized, except for one, which gets called a couple times per second and uses most of the fields. Now I'm investigating on how to optimize this query, do I:

- create an index over all fields?
- create an index over all fields and remove the individual indexes?

If I have an index over all fields, would I even need the individual indexes?

This is the query:

```
SELECT count(*) as rang_pos 
FROM results
WHERE results.created >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 24 HOUR) 
AND results.speedtest_id = 1 
AND results.checked = 1 
AND results.typing_mode = 1 
AND results.keystrokes <= 500
```

### Indexes

[image: ##enter image description here]

Comment: Can you add the output of `show index from results;` to your question please? Remember with a multi-column index, the fields need to be present in your query from left to right for the index to be used.

Comment: @DaveRix I added the indexes. So if I create a multi-column index, I have to make sure that its the same order as the query calls the individual columns?

Comment: No, sorry, I didn't explain myself very well, there is limited characters availalble in comments! I will explain more in my answer below :)

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` is more helpful than `show index`. And please use **text** output, not images.

Answer (score 1):

With a multi-field index, you need to make sure each field in the index is used from left to right in the `WHERE` clause, otherwise the index will not be applicable.
If we assume that your index `speedtest_id_2` is the only index you have (except for the primary key), then the following query *will* use the index

```
SELECT count(*) as rang_pos 
FROM results
WHERE results.created >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 24 HOUR) 
AND results.speedtest_id = 1 
AND results.checked = 1 
AND results.typing_mode = 1 
AND results.keystrokes <= 500
```

Whereas the following query will *not* use that index.

```
SELECT count(*) as rang_pos 
FROM results
WHERE results.created >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 24 HOUR) 
AND results.checked = 1 
AND results.typing_mode = 1 
AND results.keystrokes <= 500
```

as the `speedtest_id` field which is first in the index is not part of the `WHERE` clause.

With your combined index, I would add `keystrokes` to the index before the `created` field, as that will help reduce the data being read through when calculating the output. Also use the `EXPLAIN` command to view the query plan that MySQL is going to use when running the query.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) as rang_pos 
FROM results
WHERE results.created >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 24 HOUR) 
AND results.speedtest_id = 1 
AND results.checked = 1 
AND results.typing_mode = 1 
AND results.keystrokes <= 500
```

You may find that rearranging the fields in the multi-field index will change the query plan, and thereby the performance of the query.

Your `speedtest_id` single field index is not relevant, as the combined index has that field as the first field, so will be used even if you only filter on that one field.

Whether you leave the other individual field indexes in or remove them is entirely down to how your application works, and what other queries are run against it - you may find that they are all used at some point or another when your application runs.

You can leave your application running for a while, and then examine the following tables (if you have the `sys` schema installed) to see how the indexes are being used.

```
select * from sys.schema_index_statistics where object_schema = '{database}';
select * from sys.schema_unused_indexes where object_schema = '{database}';
```

This will give you an idea of which indexes are not used by the application.

Comment: The sys schema is available in MySQL from version 5.6 onwards - I use it regularly to investigate index usage -  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-schema-prerequisites.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just to clarify: If I want a combined index to be used, I have to make sure that every field inside the index is also used in the query? I'm just a bit confused about the following part: `the index is used from left to right in the WHERE clause`

Comment: one more thing about adding keystrokes: wouldn't it make more sense to have "created" before "keystrokes"? Otherwise the query would first observe all rows, instead of those in the last 24 hours or doesn't it work like this?

Comment: The fields used in your `WHERE` clause only need to match then first `n` fields in the index, and they don't have to be in the same order. You can use index fields `1,2,3` of a 4 field index, but not index fields `2,3,4`. If you use index fields `1,3,4` then the index will be used, but only the first field, as field 2 is not in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: You could try switching the `created` and `keystrokes` field around in your index, both _will_ work, but one may be more efficient than the other - always try to use the fields in order or cardinality, or how much data they will _remove_ from the results if they are applicable. `checked` for example may not be a good index field, as there are only two values - unless there are only a handful of 'not checked' records, and you want to select for those - in which case it would be excellent!

Comment: Ah, now I get it! Alright, I think I have a better understanding now, will add the new index tonight and see if it improves the query time, thank you for your help!

Comment: See also [_my index cookbook_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/)